# I fixed a weird syntax error with ejs, and I'm wondering what the issue was

Tags: html, node.js, syntax-error, ejs

I'm building a blog webpage as a personal project as a way to learn web development, and I came across this strange syntax error.  I modified my code so that logged in and logged out users would get a different navigation bar.  The following code caused an error:

```
<% if(firstp==="Welcome"){%>
        <%-include('./partials/nav2.ejs')%>
    <%}%>
    <%else%>
    <%{ %>
        <%-include('./partials/nav.ejs')%>
    <%  } %>
```

Logged in users get nav2, while logged out users are sent to the else clause and see nav.  Logged out users get the following error:

> Unexpected token 'else' in C:\Users\[REDACTED]\browse.ejs while compiling ejs

Logged in users will get the same error, or depending on exactly how I wrote my ejs, will get something like "missing parentheses" (I forgot to copy the error and how exactly to replicate it).  The following code works:

```
<% if(firstp==="Welcome"){%>
        <%-include('./partials/nav2.ejs')%>
    <%}else{ %>
        <%-include('./partials/nav.ejs')%>
    <%  } %>
```

Both are valid JavaScript syntax, so what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is related to how EJS generates the Javascript code for tags, each tag is prefixed with a semi colon`;`

The first example amounts to:

```js
; if(firstp==="Welcome"){
; include('./partials/nav2.ejs')
; }
; else
; {
; include('./partials/nav.ejs')
; }
```

The semicolons are used to separate Javascript statements from the previous tag, but in this case the semicolon ends the `if` statement.
In more common JS formatting, this is what's happening:

```js
if(firstp==="Welcome"){
  include('./partials/nav2.ejs'); 
};
else;
{
  include('./partials/nav.ejs'); 
}
```

The working example only injects semicolons inside the `if` statements curly braces `{}` which doesn't terminate the `if` statement

```js
; if(firstp==="Welcome"){
; include('./partials/nav2.ejs')
; } else {
; include('./partials/nav.ejs')
; }
```